# Convert Cartesian expression to polar expression using SymPy

Tags: python-3.x, expression, sympy, polar-coordinates

Is there a way to convert a Cartesian expression in SymPy to a polar one?
I have the following expression:

1/sqrt(x^2+y^2)

However, I can't seem to get SymPy to acknowledge that this is 1/r in polar coordinates. I tried using the 'subs' command, both of the following options (I imported sympy as asp, and defined all of the symbols earlier):

```
expr = 1/sp.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
expr.subs((x,y),(r*cos(theta),r*sin(theta))
expr.subs((sp.sqrt(x**2+y**2),sp.atan(y/x)),(r,theta))
```

but in both cases, I simply receive the original expr again.

Is there a way to convert a Cartesian expression to a polar one in SymPy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
subs((x,y),(r*cos(theta),r*sin(theta))
```

is not a correct syntax for `subs`. When multiple symbols are to be replaced, one has to provide either a dictionary

```
subs({x: r*sp.cos(theta), y: r*sp.sin(theta)})
```

or an iterable with pairs (old, new) in it:

```
subs(((x, r*sp.cos(theta)), (y, r*sp.sin(theta))))
```

The former is more readable; the latter is needed when substitutions must be carried out in a particular order (not the case here).

Either way, to achieve 1/r you also need to declare `r` as nonnegative

```
r = sp.symbols('r', nonnegative=True)
```

and simplify the result of substitution:

```
expr.subs({x: r*sp.cos(theta), y: r*sp.sin(theta)}).simplify()
```

Comment: It works now, thanks for your help! I just assumed the syntax would be like that, without questioning it.

Comment: Ok. On Stack Overflow one usually marks the best answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.